# Add a single blog page to GitHub static site

Tags: github, static, jekyll, blogs

I'm pushing a static site I coded offline to Netlify using Github.

I need a blog page. I've been looking at Jekyll but I can't find any tutorials on how to incorporate it into a single page on your site without moving the whole site over to Jekyll or creating a whole new blog site using a template.

I only need a single page with a feed of posts, using the structure and design of the rest of my site. I already have this designed but I can't figure out how to add Jekyll to it.

Is there any way to do this easily? It's just going to be a feed of text and images. I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your plain HTML files/pages in the root of your Jekyll project and set the ppermalink variable in the _config.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

To add Jekyll as a blogging platform to an existing website you need to define the sub directory where the blog will be located in your website, for example to have `/blog`, in `_config.yml` add:

```
    baseurl: "/blog"
```

If you just want a single webpage, editing `/index.md` or `/index.html` and choosing the right *layout* will be enough.